# Multiple select option

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have two select box one select box is multiple select option, there is an add more button to add multiple rows with same selectboxs, the values are passed in array format, i want to print each row multiple select options.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
     Select1   |        Select2     |         Textbox
------------------------------------------------------------------
Option1                Option1                      
Option2                Option2
Option3                Option3
Option4                Option4
```

I select first option in first select box and second select box multiple options select(Option1 and Option2), in second row i select second option in first select box and second select box multiple options select(Option3 and Option4).
I click on submit button i want to print

```
Option1             Option1
Option1             Option2

Option2             Option3
Option2             Option4
```

but now it print (takes all data from the multiple select box)

```
Option1             Option1
Option1             Option2
Option1             Option3
Option1             Option4

Option2             Option1
Option2             Option2
Option2             Option3
Option2             Option4
```

**Here is my code :**

```
<div id="lobrows">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label>Reson</label>
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="reson[]" required="required">
                    <option>--Select--</option>
                <option value="1">List 1</option>
                <option value="2">List 2</option>
                <option value="3">List 3</option>
                <option value="4">List 4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label>Service </label>
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="service[]" id="service" multiple="multiple">
                    <option>--Select--</option>
                    <option value="1">List 1</option>
                    <option value="2">List 2</option>
                    <option value="3">List 3</option>
                    <option value="4">List 4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label>Name </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="pull-right" id="add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;add</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#add').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var i=$('.mrbtm').length+1;
            $('#lobrows').append('<div class="mrbtm"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-4"><label>Reson </label><select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="reson[]"><option>--Select--</option><option value="1">List 1</option>
                <option value="2">List 2</option>
                <option value="3">List 3</option>
                <option value="4">List 4</option></select></div><div class="col-sm-4"><label>Service </label><select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="service[]" id="service'+i+'" multiple="multiple"><option>--Select--</option><option value="1">List 1</option><option value="2">List 2</option><option value="3">List 3</option><option value="4">List 4</option></select></div><div class="col-sm-4"><label>Name </label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" required="required" /></div></div><a href="#" class="pull-right remove"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Remove</a><br /></div>');
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            i--;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Here is my PHP Code :**

```
<?php
foreach ($reson as $id => $value) {
    $reson = ($reson[$id]);
    $namep = ($name[$id]);


    foreach ($service as $ii => $valu) {
        $r_service = ($service[$ii]);
        echo "Option".$reson."----"."Option".$r_service ."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all: It's not wise to reassign var which you are taking as source for foreach

```
$reson = ($reson[$id]);
```

Secondly, i can't see your form anywhere in posted code. I would suggest, you print whatever is in $_REQUEST[] (POST/GET by type of your form), and see what you will get.
I am affraid, you will see all used values from multiple selection input.
That is, because you **name** all selections (generated with js) the same name.
You should identify selections uniquely, so you can know which are which.

Now you would have more than one selection input with same name.
You can apply something like you did with id attribute when generating new inputs.

In php then, you can do something like this:

```
$i = 1;
while(true){
    if(!isset($_POST['reson'.$i])){
        break;
    }
    $selectedOptions = $_POST['reson'.$i];
    //your magic

    $i++;
}
```

Note that this code won't work when you will have gaps between "ids" of selection input names. (someone removes selection input)

Hope this helps a bit :)